# Multiple RewriteRules for a single set of RewriteConds

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We've tried all the suggestions on stackoverflow we could find for adding multiple RewriteRules for the same set of RewriteConds, but in all cases, we're only able to get the first RewriteRule to work.
This is the working code for a single rewrite that we'd like to add more categories to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /designers/$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

None of the below work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /designers/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /labels/$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  .?  -  [S=2]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /designers/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /labels/$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `[OR]` cond is almost correct. When you do a logical invert, you must also negate.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule  .?  -  [S=2]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /designers/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /labels/$1 [NC,L]
```

So you don't want `!-f`, you want `-f`. Keep in mind that the `S=2` skips **2** rules. If you have more categories you'll need to change that, or just use the `L` flag instead.

Comment: Thank you, Jon! We cleared our .htaccess file and pasted in your code, but while those in the "designers" category work -- https://www.fashion.net/designers/prada/ (original) https://www.fashion.net/prada/ (rewritten), those in the "labels" category still don't -- the original at https://www.fashion.net/labels/miss-sixty/ works while the rewritten version https://www.fashion.net/miss-sixty/ produces a 500 internal server error. What could the reason be?

Comment: Checking the error log, we found this "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace."

Comment: @haadaa It just occurred to me that your rules aren't going to work. Firstly, since both "designers" and "labels" use the exact same pattern to match (`^(.*)$` or "everything"), how do you know which one goes to which? If someone requests `/foo`, is that supposed to go to `/designers/foo` or `/labels/foo`? In order for this to work your patterns needs to be mutually exclusive of each other.

Comment: Thank you, @JonLin! Our hope was that this would work as an if, elseif chain as all profile names are unique across all categories. If that isn't possible, we'll just have to merge all categories into one.

Comment: @haadaa not possible, mod_rewrite has no idea if a given pattern is a designer or label or whatever else. If you need some other business logic for determining stuff like that, you can route *everything* into a script and have the script do whatever lookups are necessary to determine where a request should get routed to. All you have with a RewriteRule is a regex pattern, that's it.

Comment: Thank you, @JonLin! This was our first question on Stack Overflow and we're thrilled! We'll mark this as resolved (as it really, truly is, even if what we set out to do can't be done). We'll take your advice and either write a script or just merge all our categories into one. Thanks again!